# Хранение драйверов в Windows

Tags: c++, windows, драйвер, kernel

Как хранятся драйвера режима ядра в Windows?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что они находятся в системном адресном пространстве?
Можно ли осуществить ручную выгрузку драйвера в память? (Manual Mapping метод)